# Get full height of object tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need detect the full height of content inside an `<object>` tag. I'm trying to load external HTML, but it shows me a scrollbar so I want dynamically set  the height of the object and avoid showing the scrollbar.

I've tried several options, but I only found the height of the `object` tag, not the content inside the object. Do you know of any solutions?

```html
<object data="https://www.second-domain.com/test.html" type="text/html" style="width:100%;height:100vh"></object>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have control over the content you're loading in to the `object` (as there's better approaches you could use if you did), so you can't access cross-domain content from the parent window, which you would need to do in order to calculate the height.

Comment: If the content is loaded from a different origin than your own page in which you are embedding this - then you don't have JavaScript access to the content at all. Keyword Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Just dont use `height:100vh` and it should auto set to the height of content